# Upload multiple files to Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, parameterized

I am manually creating text files in remote windows location to build a job in Jenkins.

Is this possible using any plugin , that i can create these files in Jenkins workspace.
[image]

Currenlty i checked File Operations Plugin , but this does not create different files as this one is only uploading a single file.